# Get position information for videoframes of a video source/probe in CustusX

Tags: plugins

In a custom plugin for the extension of CustusX which implements `GUIExtenderService` I want to access the streamed image of an ultrasound probe together with its position.

The [Documentation](http://www.custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/classcx_1_1_video_service.html) says:

> **VideoSource** has two main users: Rendering to screen and recording to disk. **VideoGraphics** contains the visualization functionality that the Reps uses when rendering in the Views. **VideoGraphics** needs a **Probe** to provide position information. **Probe** also wraps the **VideoSource** with its own ProbeAdapterVideoSource (using the adapter pattern) in order to add special information not known to the VideoSource, such as pixel spacing.

So to my understanding, `VideoSource` is responsible for the image and `Probe` for the position. If I start with the `VideoSource` and hook up to `newFrame` and retrieve the image with `getVtkImageData` I only get the image data. So the question is: How can I obtain both an image frame and its corresponding position information for that frame? (Either via `VideoSource` and `Probe` or by other means).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of the `Probe` and related objects:

```
VisServicesPtr services = VisServices::create(context);
ToolPtr tool = services->trackingService->getTool("myprobe");
ProbePtr probe = tool->getProbe();
VideoSourcePtr video = probe->getRTSource();
```

Now you have a `tool`, containing a `probe`, containing a `video`. `video` provides the image stream, while `tool` and `probe` provides position info. According to [the documentation](http://custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/cx_us_probe_definition.html#cx_us_probe_spaces), the position of the image can be expressed as a transform `rMv`, where r is the global reference space and v is the image space in millimeters. To convert to pixels, multiply by the image spacing. `rMv` can be found using:

```
Transform3D rMpr, prMt, tMu, uMv, rMv;
rMpr = services->patientModelService->get_rMpr();
prMt = tool->get_prMt();
tMu = probe->getSector()->get_tMu();
uMv = probe->getSector()->get_uMv();
rMv = rMpr*prMt*tMu*uMv;
```

The transform `rMpr` is the patient registration and is identity if you are doing streaming only.

Now, a pixel position p in pixels can be converted to global space r using:

```
Vector3D p_v(p[0]*spacing[0], p[1]*spacing[1])    
Vector3D p_r = rMv.coord(p_v);
```

Note: The position gotten this way will be the last sampled tracking position, not necessarily obtained simultaneously with the image frame. Interpolating with the next tracking position (recived after the image frame) can increase accuracy, but this is dependent on the specific use case.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the naming scheme and should have read the [coordinate system documentation](http://custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/coordinate_systems.html). So `r` is the global, `pr` the patient, `t` the tool, `u` the ultrasound plane and `v` the inverted ultrasound plane. Maybe comments like `tool->get_prMt(); // patient space -> tool space` and analog for the other transforms would make the example code somewhat easier to read.

Comment: It could be added that to run the code, in CMakeLists.txt, cxResourceVisualization has to be in  PLUGIN_target_libraries to be able to include cxVisServices.h in the include path. I could include the rest of the necessary headers without problems (cxProbeSector.h, cxPatientModelService.h, and cxTransform3D.h).

Comment: When working with coordinates and spaces, notation is everything. CustusX consistently uses the space names r, pr, t, u etc, and the notation p_b = bMa*p_a for transformations. This also gives readable chained transforms (i.e. p_c = cMb*bMa*p_a). I prefer this to comments that duplicate code and might deviate from the code as time passes.